# Angular 2 final - change route parameter on the URL programmatically

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Assume I'm actually the page "results"...

http://server/results;dateFrom=03-11-2016;page=1

Me as the results page, I'd like to load the page 2, but I need to set the URL string on the browser to http://server/results;dateFrom=03-11-2016;page=2 just in case if someone decide to bookmark it.

so, how to programmatically change the URL parameter on the Web Browser Address Bar ?

ty !

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it with this code:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// ...

constructor(private router: Router) {}

changeRoute () {
  this.router.navigate(['/results', { dateFrom: this.dateFrom, page: this.page }]);
}

// ...
```

Take a look at this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-parameters).

---

Further information can be found at the [API description of router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#usage-3).

Comment: how does this look in app.module.ts?

Comment: @Omar I've added a Stackblitz demo to my answer.