# RouterLink in Angular CLI / TypeScript method?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have to import my URL link (actionsConfig) to my component.

In HTML I used to use "router link", how does it work in TypeScript?

actionsConfig.ts :

```
export const ACTIONS = [
  {
    label: 'Delete',
    actionType: 'DELETE',
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    actionType: 'GO_TO',
    getUrl: row => '/detail/' + row.id,
  },
];
```

component.ts :

```
actionFunc(action, user: User) {
if (action.actionType === 'DELETE') {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') === true) {
    /*delete ok*/
  }
}
if (action === 'GO_TO') {
  const url = action.getUrl(user);
  /* GO TO URL (routerlink?) */
}
```

}

Comment: you can inject the `Router` and navigate using `this.router.navigateTo(URL)`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 final - change route parameter on the URL programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405775/angular-2-final-change-route-parameter-on-the-url-programmatically)

Comment: I added "private router: Router" to the constructor and " this.router.navigate(url);" to the method.
I get "Promise returned from navigate is ignored" on "navigate"  and nothing happens when I click on edit (html page)
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
This one worked for me.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  }


  /.../
  if (action.actionType === 'GO_TO') {
      console.log('test');
      const url = action.getUrl(user);
      this.router.navigateByUrl(url).then();
    }
```